# HTML5 Video: Canvas Mirror slow

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-video

My Functionality works fine, but after few loops it's slowing down and the "mirrored" video stutters a bit.

Is a way to make it faster/smoother?

I'd like to understand if I chosen the right way on mirroring the videos.

I have clip path in css, and they have to be 3 on which I have video inside mirrored. Firstly looks really good, but then after few loops the mirrored videos run slowly and

Please help.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('video1');
    var canvasBottom = document.getElementById('mycanvasbottom');
    var canvasLeft = document.getElementById('mycanvasleft');
    var canvasRight = document.getElementById('mycanvasright');
  
    var contextB = canvasBottom.getContext('2d');
    var contextL = canvasLeft.getContext('2d');
    var contextR = canvasRight.getContext('2d');

    var cw = 640;
    var ch = 480;
    canvasBottom.width = cw;
    canvasBottom.height = ch;
    canvasLeft.width = cw;
    canvasLeft.height = ch;
    canvasRight.width = cw;
    canvasRight.height = ch
  
    v.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
        draw(this,contextL,cw,ch);
        draw(this,contextR,cw,ch);
        draw(this,contextB,cw,ch);
    },false);
      

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
```

```css
#mycanvasbottom {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 50% 50%, 100% 100%);
}
#mycanvasleft {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 0 100%);
}
#mycanvasright {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 100%);
}

#video1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id='mycanvasbottom' ></canvas>
<canvas id='mycanvasleft' ></canvas>
<canvas id='mycanvasright' ></canvas>

<video id='video1' autoplay muted loop width='320' >
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, "timeupdate" event is fired multiple times - so you are actually calling draw much more times than you want. This is the reason why it starts lagging - many operations are executed per second. You may probably listen to "play" and "pause" events (fired after play() and pause() methods being executed; "play" event is also called when the video begins, so you don't have to call it manually, it will be fired anyway). Then you can manually handle your drawing loop. That should solve your problem(I was able to reproduce and it fixes the slow down effect).

Also, here are some tips you may consider:

1. Do NOT use setTimeout() for animations, especially when playing with canvas. Read about window.requestAnimationFrame(), which is far better, and consider using it instead.
2. You may consider many optimizations in that code, for example generating canvas elements in your code(to get rid of ids), using Object.assign() to add multiple properties to an object in the same line, introduce loops. Volume of that code will decrease drastically. It is not a must, but it is always good to maintain code quality. Simply - less work in the future.

Regards and Have a nice day!

Edit:
Don't get me wrong, some of this is only about personal preferences. After working quite a lot with js, I like to keep it simple, like in this snippet. Enjoy free code!

```js
let lastAnimationFrameRequestId = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const cw = 640;
    const ch = 480;
    const video = document.getElementById('video1');
    const canvases = [];
    const clipPaths = [
        'clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 50% 50%, 100% 100%)',
        'clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 50%, 0 100%);',
        'clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 100%)'
    ];

    clipPaths.forEach((clipPath) => {
        const canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), { className: 'my-canvas', style: clipPath, width: cw, height: ch });
        canvases.push(canvas);
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });

    video.addEventListener('play', () => window.requestAnimationFrame(() => draw(video, canvases)));
    video.addEventListener('pause', () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(lastAnimationFrameRequestId));
});

function draw(video, canvases) {
    canvases.forEach((canvas) => {
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    });
    lastAnimationFrameRequestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => draw(video, canvases));
}
```

```css
.my-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

```html
<video id='video1' autoplay muted loop width='320'>
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed well explained answer. I really appreciated. It wouldn't be possible to achieve it in million years with out you!

Comment: Do you know how to add a blur effect to the canvas left and right? 
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 50%, 100% 100%);filter:blur(4px); 
Something like this? looks like brakes a bit the shape

Comment: Good old friend when working with JS is console.log() - often it is most useful tool for debugging JS for me. Simple, always working. Try changing CSS, property -webkit-filter from "-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);" to "-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) blur(4px);". You can mix multiple filters just separating them with space. Also might want to add "-moz-filter" and "filter" for browser compatibility.

Comment: COuld you help me width something else? What about if I have another video and I want to replicare the canvas with another video? would it work without duplicating the code?

Comment: Do not duplicate the code! If you need to reuse some part, extract it to a function and then call it with wanted element.This line "const video = document.getElementById('video1');" needs to be parametrized. Consider it and play a bit with it.

Comment: Hi mike, I put together some code on a demo, https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/vwpKxN?editors=1010 could you check if I done it right please?

Comment: Hi Mike do you know how to make it working on safari?